# Powershell Custom object - not passing foreach variable

Tags: loops, powershell, hashtable, pscustomobject, formattable

I'm trying to create a custom object based on server names from a text file. 
The script I have goes and imports the txt file into a Variable. Then runs a foreach server in the servers variable to create the custom object. I would like to be able to output the object's properties as a table that doesn't include the header info each time.

See script and output below:

```
 $SERVERS = gc c:\servers.txt


foreach ($srv in $SERVERS)
{
    $Obj = New-Object PsObject -Property`
   @{
         Computername = $srv
         SecurityGroup = (Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof
         RebootDay = ((Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof).split(',').split(' ')[2]
         Combined = ((Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof).split(',').split(' ').split('=')[1]
         RebootTime = $obj.combined.substring(0,4)
     }

 echo $obj | ft Computername,RebootDay -autosize

}
```

This is the output currently:

Computername  RebootDay

---

SERVER007      Sunday

Computername  RebootDay

---

SERVER009     Sunday

Computername  RebootDay

---

SERVER003      Sunday

---

I'd like it to look more like:

Computername  RebootDay

---

SERVER007     Sunday
SERVER001     Sunday
SERVER009     Sunday

Answer (score 3):

TessellatingHeckler was on the right track really. The issue with his code is that you can't pipe a `ForEach($x in $y){}` loop to anything (not to be confused with a `ForEach-Object` loop that you usually see shortened to just `ForEach` like `$Servers | ForEach{<code here>}`) You don't want to pipe objects to `Format-Table` one at a time, you want to pipe a collection of objects to it so that it looks nice. So here's the modified code:

```
$SERVERS = gc c:\servers.txt

$Results = foreach ($srv in $SERVERS)
{
    New-Object PsObject -Property @{
         Computername = $srv
         SecurityGroup = (Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof
         RebootDay = ((Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof).split(',').split(' ')[2]
         Combined = ((Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof).split(',').split(' ').split('=')[1]
         RebootTime = $obj.combined.substring(0,4)
     }
}
$Results | FT ComputerName,RebootDay -auto
```

That collects the objects in an array, then you pass the whole array to `Format-Table`

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the "ft" (Format-Table) command inside the loop, put it outside, once, at the end. e.g.

```
$SERVERS = gc c:\servers.txt

$results = foreach ($srv in $SERVERS)
{
    $Obj = New-Object PsObject -Property`
   @{
         Computername = $srv
         SecurityGroup = (Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof
         RebootDay = ((Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof).split(',').split(' ')[2]
         Combined = ((Get-QADComputer $srv).memberof).split(',').split(' ').split('=')[1]
         RebootTime = $obj.combined.substring(0,4)
     }
    $Obj
} 
$results | ft Computername,RebootDay -autosize
```

Edit: Fixed for foreach pipeline bug.

You could possibly neaten it a bit because you don't need to make a new PSObject for a hashtable, and then put the object into the pipeline; you don't need to repeat the Get-QADComputer commands three times. I'm suspicious that the `$obj.combined` line isn't doing anything - how can you refer to an object inside the properties of the new-object call, before it gets assigned that name? And the repeated `splits` could probably be combined because it operates on individual characters, not strings.

```
gc c:\servers.txt | foreach {
    $memberof = (Get-QADComputer $_).memberof

    @{
        Computername = $_;
        SecurityGroup = $memberof;
        RebootDay = $memberof.split(', ')[2];
        Combined = $memberof.split(', =')[1];
        # ?? RebootTime = $obj.combined.substring(0,4)
    }
} | ft Computername,RebootDay -autosize
```

Comment: You can not pipe output of a `ForEach` loop to anything (not to be confused with the inline `ForEach-Object` loop that can be shortened to `ForEach`). Instead do something like `$Results = ForEach($srv in $SERVERS){<same code here>};$Results|FT ComputerName,RebootDay -auto`